# How to get values in a non-constant position?

Tags: regex, perl

String contains:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1439890,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
```

The order of key-value pairs is not constant. Examples:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1439890,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890
```

How to get values in a non-constant position of pairs using one regular expression?
This example is for the permanent position of pairs:

```
my $str = '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1439890,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"';
if ($str =~/#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=(?'bandwidth'.+?),RESOLUTION=(?'resolution'.+?),CODECS="(?'codecs'.+?)"$/) {
    say $+{bandwidth};
    say $+{resolution};
    say $+{codecs};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use positive lookahead:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    print;
    if (/^#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:(?=.*BANDWIDTH=(?'bandwidth'[^,]+))(?=.*RESOLUTION=(?'resolution'[^,]+))(?=.*CODECS="(?'codecs'[^"]+))/) {
        say $+{bandwidth};
        say $+{resolution};
        say $+{codecs};
    } else {
        say 'NO match';
    }
}

__DATA__
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1439890,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890
```

**Output:**

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1439890,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
1439890
640x480
avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"
1439890
640x480
avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=14398901439890
640x480
avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2
```

Comment: Your codecs value is wrong. It should be `avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2`, not `avc1.42001f`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to extract all values into a hash first:

```
use v5.12.0;
use warnings;

my @variants = (
    '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1439890,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"',
    '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890,CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2"',
    '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:CODECS="avc1.42001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x480,BANDWIDTH=1439890',
);

for my $str (@variants) {
    say "trying $str ...";
    my %data = $str =~ /(\w+)=(?|([^",]+)|"([^"]*)")/g;

    say "bandwidth:  $data{BANDWIDTH}";
    say "resolution: $data{RESOLUTION}";
    say "codecs:     $data{CODECS}";
    say "";
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/ekLGZS).

`m//g` in list context tries to match as many times as possible and returns a list of all captured strings. In this case, every match contributes two captures (because of the branch reset pattern `(?|...)` the last two alternatives count as one group).

Assigning a list to a hash interprets the elements at even positions as keys and the odd elements as the corresponding values.